# How to use gcc sanitizers

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

Why does this not work?:

prog.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\n%d\n%d\n", i, j);
    
    return 0;
}
```

debug file:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O0 -g3 -fsanitize=address -o temp/debug.out src/prog.c
./temp/debug.out
```

running:

```
./debug
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:6:9: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
        printf("\n%d\n%d\n", i, j);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.c:6:9: warning: ‘j’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

0
0
==90==LeakSanitizer has encountered a fatal error
==90==HINT: For debugging, try setting environment variable LSAN_OPTION=verbosity=1:log_threads=1
==90==LeakSanitizer does not work under ptrace (strace, gdb, etc)
```

I'm new to using debuging tools but there isn't much to read on this topic except man pages of compilers. So please can someone help me?

This was executed on Windows 10 subsystem for linux (Ubuntu) on freshly openned terminal.

I'd like to use `-fno-sanitize=all` option I found in man pages of `gcc` but it doesn't seem to say a word on any mistake I came up with.

Comment: Don't post images of text, or external links. Copy-paste the text (as text) into the actual question instead. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Try the advise it gives you in a line with `HINT`.

Comment: i tried `LSAN_OPTION=verbosity=1:log_threads=1` right after #! /bin/bash

Comment: thank you for rewriting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out it was problem of WSL i used (I didn't think it was important to say i use one)

Turns out i need to write `LSAN_OPTION=verbosity=1:log_threads=1; g++ -Wall...`